# How toxic is tile dust after a remodel is done?

Tags: tile, removal

We recently remodeled the downstairs in our home. We took out about 400 sq feet of tile all the way down to the concrete. We are going to put in new vinyl flooring but haven't done that yet. They used a lot more of the thin set than usual so it took 4 days to take the tile off and ground down the remaining thin set. Dust got everywhere on every surface imaginable. I've read that tile dust is very bad for you and can cause lung problems and cancer. We were out of the house for 4 days while the tiles were being taken out but the dust has settled a lot and we are back in the house after a 4 hour dust clean up. Is the tile dust still in the air and on surfaces bad for us and cause issues down the road or are we safe to live here again with family?

Comment: Check out the incidence of lung problems with people who work in the industry for 10, 20 or 30 years. Will you be in contact with the dust for that long?

Comment: With most things it is the amount and length of time.  Water becomes toxic if you drink a few gallons in a day.  Probably have more to worry about breathing in polluted air 24/7 for years.

Comment: I've read that coffee's bad for you. I've read that wine's bad for you. According to the State of California, _everything_ is bad for you. Take what you read with a grain of salt, look closely at the _conditions_ in which they tested to determine that it's bad for you, then determine if those conditions apply to you. [Saccharin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccharin) caused cancer in rats - when they fed them the equivalent of about 36 cans of Coke worth a day, but nobody cared about that minor detail...

Comment: From that link: "In the 1970s, studies performed on laboratory rats found an association between consumption of high doses of saccharin and the development of bladder cancer.[10] However, further study determined that this effect was due to a mechanism that is not relevant to humans (deposition of crystals; see History section).[10] Epidemiological studies have shown no evidence that saccharin is associated with bladder cancer in humans.[10][11]". Because of a couple of flawed studies, you cannot get anything with saccharin in it. Not supporting saccharin, just careful reading.

Comment: "Safe" is highly subjective, making this question off topic.

Comment: If you have forced air heat/cooling, you might want to run it on 'fan' (if it's not already running) and change out your filters more frequently for a while.  At the very least check your filter and make sure it's not clogged.  A badly clogged filter can damage your equipment.

Comment: Was the tile asbestos? A lot depends on what the tile was made of.

Answer (score 1):

I did this kind of work without a mask for 20+ years after all the years of doing this I am now a great grampa so will you have any issues either dust after the work has been completed?
Heck NO unless you snort it,
Maybe just my opinion but after working
With tile and many construction buddies that demoed and rebuilt cement structures I do not think you are at risk at all based on my and many other construction professionals life experiences.